# xsl:value-of select from a specific line XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am quite new to XSLT and have a problem. My code looks like this:

```
<xsl:element name="relatedArticle1">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(ancestor-or-self::node()/CrossSelling/CSArtikel/@ArtikelNr,'-','')"/>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="relatedArticle2">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(ancestor-or-self::node()/CrossSelling/CSArtikel/@ArtikelNr[@Index = '2'],'-','')"/>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="relatedArticle3">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(ancestor-or-self::node()/CrossSelling/CSArtikel/@ArtikelNr[@Index = '3'],'-','')"/>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="relatedArticle4">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(ancestor-or-self::node()/CrossSelling/CSArtikel/@ArtikelNr[@Index = '4'],'-','')"/>
</xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="relatedArticle5">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(ancestor-or-self::node()/CrossSelling/CSArtikel/@ArtikelNr[@Index = '5'],'-','')"/>
</xsl:element>
```

What it is supposed to do:

it should give me

```
<relatedArticle1>2810000001</relatedArticle1>
<relatedArticle1>2810000002</relatedArticle1>
```

because the XML file looks like this:

```
<CrossSelling>
    <CSArtikel Index="1" BildNr="009710" ArtikelNr="281-00-00001" FabrikartikelNr="Shoe Clean 905768" />
    <CSArtikel Index="2" BildNr="009709" ArtikelNr="281-00-00002" FabrikartikelNr="Combi Pflege Schaum 905859" />
    <CSArtikel Index="3" BildNr="009713" ArtikelNr="062-00-00010" FabrikartikelNr="Nano Plus 906992" />
    <CSArtikel Index="4" BildNr="009720" ArtikelNr="062-00-00011" FabrikartikelNr="906802" />
    <CSArtikel Index="5" BildNr="008667" ArtikelNr="069-00-00008" FabrikartikelNr="Poliertuch 905856" />
</CrossSelling>
```

but it doesn't.

so `[@Index = '3']` to choose line 3 f.e. doesn't work.

How can i change the code so it gets from the different lines?

Comment: If you need to create an element and the name is static, don't use `xsl:element` (unless you just really love typing extra characters). It makes your XSLT harder to read. Just use an element literal, and follow @Tomalak advice.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly dis-recommend creating "counted" clement names. If there are three instances of a thing, like a "related article", then they are of the same type. They should have the same name.

"Related article #3" is not supposed to be `<relatedArticle3>` but simply the third `<relatedArticle>` in the row.

Apart from that, you don't need to use `<xsl:element>` for elements with a predefined name. Just write `<element>` directly.

Finally, your approach is *much* too complex. Use `<xsl:apply-templates>` and relative XPaths, for example like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <relatedArticles>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="CSArtikel" />
    </relatedArticles>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CSArtikel">
    <relatedArticle>
      <xsl:value-of select="@ArtikelNr" />
    </relatedArticle>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which results in:

```
<relatedArticles>
   <relatedArticle>281-00-00001</relatedArticle>
   <relatedArticle>281-00-00002</relatedArticle>
   <relatedArticle>062-00-00010</relatedArticle>
   <relatedArticle>062-00-00011</relatedArticle>
   <relatedArticle>069-00-00008</relatedArticle>
</relatedArticles>
```

If you want to get the third article from that at some point, it's as easy as `/relatedArticles/relatedArticle[3]`, however not having every element with a different name will make any kind of XML processing later on *much* easier.

Answer (score 0):

ok I just had it in wrong position.

this works:

```
                                <xsl:element name="relatedArticle1">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(ancestor-or-self::node()/CrossSelling/CSArtikel/@ArtikelNr,'-','')"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                            <xsl:element name="relatedArticle2">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(ancestor-or-self::node()/CrossSelling/CSArtikel[@Index = '2']/@ArtikelNr,'-','')"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                            <xsl:element name="relatedArticle3">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(ancestor-or-self::node()/CrossSelling/CSArtikel[@Index = '3']/@ArtikelNr,'-','')"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                            <xsl:element name="relatedArticle4">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(ancestor-or-self::node()/CrossSelling/CSArtikel[@Index = '4']/@ArtikelNr,'-','')"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                            <xsl:element name="relatedArticle5">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(ancestor-or-self::node()/CrossSelling/CSArtikel[@Index = '5']/@ArtikelNr,'-','')"/>
                            </xsl:element>
```